# Check username with ajax jquery php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have table users :

- id : int,
- username : varchar(255),
- password :varchar(255),

I would check if the login exist in the database or not

I try with this code jquery and html :

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">username <span class="required">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  name="username " id="username ">
          <span id="availablity"></span>
     </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){
            $('#username').blur(function(){
                var username = $(this).val();
                $.ajax ({
                    url = "check.php",
                    method = "POST",
                    data =  {username :username },
                    dataType : "text",
                    success:function(html)
                    {
                        $('#availablity').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

page check.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
                $username  = $_POST["username"];
                $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username  = '$username'");
                if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
                     echo '<span class="text-danger">Not Exist</span>';
                }else{
                    echo '<span class="text-success">Exist</span>';
                }

}
```

**But no results**

Comment: what the result of your console.log(html)?

Comment: [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)!

Comment: For security reasons: you really should escape your username. Currently your application is vulnerable for SQL injections.

Comment: Apart from that, your logic is wrong: `rowCount()>0` should return "Exists"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code.

JavaScript code

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
          $('#username').change(function(){
               var username = $(this).val();
                $.ajax ({
                    url : "check.php",
                    method : "POST",
                    data :  {username :username },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success:function(html)
                    {
                        $('#availablity').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
   });
```

And you've mentioned id="username " (with space), please change that like as below.

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  name="username" id="username">
```

Comment: @johansson, you accepted my answer and then removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have used = in your ajax configuration. Thats an syntax error. Use

```
$.ajax({
    url: "check.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {username: username},
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (html) {
        $('#availablity').html(html);
    }
});
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

looks Jquery syntax error ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){
            $('#username').blur(function(){
                var username = $(this).val();
                $.ajax ({
                    url : "check.php",
                    method : "POST",
                    data :  {username :username },
                    dataType : "text",
                    success:function(html)
                    {
                        console.log(html);
                        $('#availablity').html(html);

                    },
                    error: function(html)
                    {
                        console.log(html);
                    }
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

check your console message.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
            $('#username').blur(function(){

                var username = $(this).val();
                $.ajax ({
                    url :"check.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data : {username :username },
                    dataType : "text",
                    success:function(html)
                    {
                        $('#check').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```